# Average of "n" most recent data points

Tags: excel, excel-formula, aggregate

I have a large spreadsheet containing the statistics of all basketball games played by all players for the season. I'm trying to find the average minutes played over the previous 5 games.

Here is a link to download the sheet:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sHsOoIGpqjv08UKIeu476U8jKx633s8A/view?usp=sharing

In the "RAW" tab is all of my raw data loaded from a website. In the "DATA" tab is where I am consolidating my desired data.

In columns B:E I have collected some of my desired data based on player names. The challenge is I don't know how to collect data based on a player's name AND the 5 most recent data points.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In Data!F2,

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(RAW!I:I, AGGREGATE(14, 6, ROW(INDEX(RAW!C:C, MATCH(A2, RAW!C:C, 0)):INDEX(RAW!C:C, MATCH("zzz", RAW!C:C)))/(INDEX(RAW!C:C, MATCH(A2, RAW!C:C, 0)):INDEX(RAW!C:C, MATCH("zzz", RAW!C:C))=A2), MIN(5, COUNTIF(RAW!C:C, A2)))):INDEX(RAW!I:I, AGGREGATE(14, 6, ROW(INDEX(RAW!C:C, MATCH(A2, RAW!C:C, 0)):INDEX(RAW!C:C, MATCH("zzz", RAW!C:C)))/(INDEX(RAW!C:C, MATCH(A2, RAW!C:C, 0)):INDEX(RAW!C:C, MATCH("zzz", RAW!C:C))=A2), 1)))
```

Fill down. Note that 'Josh Smith' only has four entries so I've use MIN and COUNTIF to adjust the five entries to four.

[image]

This solution does rely upon the *First Last* names in Raw!C:C being sorted.

Comment: Changing my formula to look at column `I`, as yours does, I get different results for some of the names (eg Frank Mason III). On the sheet I downloaded, his most recent 5 data points are `{19.5;19;18;22.5;22}` which averages 20.2.  Your formula returns 21.6.

Comment: I was counting from the bottom up; e.g. {22.5, 22, 21, 20.5, 22} which was what I interpreted as the *'5 most recent'* (i.e. the last five entries). Personally, I'm at terminal **meh** point with all the vagaries.

Comment: Ah, that explains it.  I figured most recent based on the order that the dates were sorted in the Date column; so I counted top down. And concur with the vagaries of some posts.

Comment: Never bothered looking for dates; didn't even look that hard for which column to average.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this formula, it works with your data as is, and the records dont need to be in any particular order.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--((RAW!$M$2:$M$4388)*(RAW!$C$2:$C$4388=DATA!A2)*(RAW!$D$2:$D$4388>=LARGE((RAW!$C$2:$C$4388=DATA!A2)*(RAW!$D$2:$D$4388),5))))/MIN(COUNTIF(RAW!$C$2:$C$4388,DATA!A2),5)
```

Edited to give average instead of sum. Also, please notice that this returns different values from @Jeeped 's solution - I think it's because he is excluding 0s, whereas mine includes them.

[image: Screenshot of result]

Comment: No, I just guessed at the column to average; I used column I, it seems that it should have been column M. Once I figured that out, I looked at the effort the OP had made in his original post and said to myself *why bother?*.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works great! The only issue I'm having now is that this data lists a game where a player "played" 0 minutes, but ideally if they play 0 minutes, then the result should be ignored. Any ideas?

Comment: Or if it's easier, I want to ignore any games where column N result is 0.

Comment: UNTESTED: `=SUMPRODUCT(--((RAW!$M$2:$M$4388)*(RAW!$C$2:$C$4388=DATA!A2)*(RAW!$D$2:$D$4388>=LARGE((RAW!$C$2:$C$4388=DATA!A2)*(RAW!$D$2:$D$4388),5))))/MIN(COUNTIFS(RAW!$C$2:$C$4388,DATA!A2, RAW!$M$2:$M$4388, ">0"),5)` but if it works you can mark as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Here is another formula.

It assumes

- Names are sorted
- Within each name, the dates are sorted descending as you show, so that we just need to look at the first five (or fewer) entries.

---

```
=AVERAGE(N(OFFSET(RAW!$M$1,-1+AGGREGATE(15,6,  1/1/(A2=First__Last)*ROW(First__Last),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&MIN(5,COUNTIF(First__Last,A2))))),0)))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>and then hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>

Not sure which column you want the data points from.  I chose `M` and note the `Raw!$M$1` entry which makes that determination.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to me that making a single formula that would do all the things I'm asking for would be tricky and a bit messy, so instead I just made an additional column that counted the game# for a player. I then made another column that was equal to "playerName"&"game#." I then had a unique cell value that I could index/match for "n" number of games.

Thanks for all of the help!